# How to change hline thickness in tabular?

Tags: tables, formatting, rules

I am just trying to get the table to look like the picture in [the LaTeX Wiki book](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Basic_examples):

[image: Table example]

In this example shown, the very top and bottom `\hline` are thicker and darker than the ones in the middle of the table. The example does not show any special formatting, but when I do this in my document they all have the same thickness and darkness (the lines are all identical). I want the horizontal `\hline` to be thinner and lighter in the middle of the table as shown in the picture. Playing with the height and width had no discernible effect on this from what I could tell. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your `\thickhline` using TeX primitives:

```
\def\thickhline{\noalign{\hrule height.8pt}}
```

So, the example from [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408870/34355) looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\thickhline{\noalign{\hrule height.8pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l | c | r }
  \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \hline
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  \hline
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{ l | c | r }
  \thickhline
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \hline
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  \hline
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \thickhline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

with exactly the same output.

Answer (score 14):

You can define your own `\thickhline` which is based on `\hline`, but with a different `\arrayrulewidth`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\thickhline{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height \thickarrayrulewidth \futurelet
   \reserved@a\@xthickhline}
\def\@xthickhline{\ifx\reserved@a\thickhline
               \vskip\doublerulesep
               \vskip-\thickarrayrulewidth
             \fi
      \ifnum0=`{\fi}}
\makeatother

\newlength{\thickarrayrulewidth}
\setlength{\thickarrayrulewidth}{2\arrayrulewidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l | c | r }
  \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \hline
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  \hline
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{ l | c | r }
  \thickhline
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \hline
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  \hline
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \thickhline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

In the above example, `\thickhline` inserts an `\hrule` that has a width double that of `\arrayrulewidth`. The latter has a default of `0.4pt`. You can change `\thickhline`'s width to whatever you want by adjusting `\thickarrayrulewidth`.

Comment: This is very close, but the default `\hrule` width is still much thicker than that shown in the example. The standard `\hrule` is already thick enough, I need an even thinner one in between. I tried just reversing `2\arrayrulewidth` to `arrayrulewidth\2` but that won't compile.

Comment: @Dan: Then adjust `\arrayrulewidth` to something smaller than `0.4pt`. Note that your viewer might snap to certain widths, making things appear thicker/thinner than they truly are.

Comment: I tried 0.1 and 0.01 and neither is thin enough. It barely made any change. It almost looks like maybe the inner lines are in a lighter gray in that image, maybe that will help. Not sure why their example appears to use formatting but they use it as a basic example without showing that formatting.

Comment: @Dan: Try [this paste](https://pastebin.com/x8GY3XJn). Output: [Adobe Reader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onQZy.png); [SumatraPDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZWnq.png), both @ 400% zoom.

Comment: So the default settings look nothing like the example they showed in their book is the issue here. I expected it to look like the book. They drew the image in the book as an SVG, it's not a LaTeX screenshot.

Comment: @Dan -- i haven't followed the links, but `\arrayrulewidth/2` isn't the correct syntax.  if you want a fractional value, you have to use a decimal: `.5\arrayrulewidth`.  (or `0.5` if you're really fastidious.)

Comment: @Dan: I assume their rendering as SVG allows for different zoom levels within the browser to still present the content in a reasonable fashion. Not exactly sure how they rendered the original tables though.

Comment: I've marked this as accepted answer (and upvoted) because the issue here is the book not showing an accurate representation of LaTeX output but instead they drew their example with a vector graphic ([view SVG source here](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/ccf3801644401d7484dc96482fd88e459112cbe0)).

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks, that was a typo sorry. But I did not know how to do that so thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Three other possibilities:

- the `makecell` package, in addition to allowing linebreaks in standard cells, defines  the `\Xhline` and `\Xcline` commands which have the rule thickness  as a mandatory argument.
- the `boldline` package (from the `shipunov` bundle) defines `\hlineB` and `clineB` which take a *numeric* argument (how many times `\arrayrulewidth`, which defaults to 0.4pt). In addition, you can have varying thickness vertical rules, with `V{some number}` in the table preamble, in the place of `|`.
- `booktabs` – which isn't really designed for that ;o) – allows to have thick horizontal rules compatible with vertical lines, with the `\specialrule` command, which takes three arguments: its thickness and the padding above and below. So I defined a shortcut for which the padding is set to 0. Advantage of booktabs: it's compatible with `\arrayrulecolor` whereas the first two are not.

Demo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, boldline, makecell, booktabs}
\newcommand\btrule[1]{\specialrule{#1}{0pt}{0pt}}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l!{\vline width 1pt}c | r }
  \arrayrulecolor{IndianRed} \Xhline{1pt}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \hline
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  \hline
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{ lV{2.5}c | r }
  \hlineB{2.5}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \hline
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  \hline
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \hlineB{2.5}
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{ l!{\color{IndianRed}\vline width 1pt}c | r }
  \arrayrulecolor{IndianRed}
  \btrule{1pt}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \arrayrulecolor{black} \hline
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  \hline
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \arrayrulecolor{IndianRed}\btrule{1pt}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you specify all the characteristic of a TikZ rule (eg `thick`) in optional argument of `|` and `\Hline` (the version of `\hline` in `nicematrix`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2pt}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|[tikz=thick]c|c|}
\Hline[tikz=thick]
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\Hline
4 & 5 & 6 \\
\Hline
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\Hline[tikz=thick]
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

If you want, you can define shortcuts with the standard commands `\newcolumntype` and `\newcommand` (or `\def` of TeX, etc.).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2pt}

\newcolumntype{I}{|[tikz=thick]}
\newcommand{\MyHline}{\Hline[tikz=thick]}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|cIc|c|}
\MyHline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\Hline
4 & 5 & 6 \\
\Hline
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\MyHline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

It's still possible to add an option to that command `\MyHline` and that letter `I` to change the color of the rule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2pt}

\newcolumntype{I}{|[tikz=thick]}
\newcommand{\MyHline}{\Hline[tikz=thick]}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|cI[color=blue]c|c|}
\MyHline[color=red]
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\Hline
4 & 5 & 6 \\
\Hline
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\MyHline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the third code]

However, `nicematrix` provides a tool to define both the letter and the command for the same type of rule (and these definitions will be available only in the environments of `nicematrix`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2pt}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
     {
       command = MyHline ,
       letter = I ,
       tikz = { color = red, line width = 1 pt } , 
       total-width = 1pt 
     }
  }

\begin{NiceTabular}{|cIc|c|}
\MyHline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\Hline
4 & 5 & 6 \\
\Hline
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\MyHline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

With this code, **a reservation is done for the rules** (vertically and horizontally) thanks to the key `total-width`.

[image: Output of the last code]