# \hline not working inside tables

Tags: tables, tabularx, hline

I want horizontal lines between each row in the table. I use this code for the table. However, it shows only vertical lines.

Here is my code(Please ignore the values inside table)

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Comparison of Accuracy, Precision and Recall}
\label{table_example}
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Method & Accuracy & Precision & Recall \\
\hline
Author 1 (2019) & 97.93 & 76.72 & 76.72\\
\hline
Author 2 (2017) & 93.36 & 0.78 & 76.72\\
\hline
Author 3 (2019) & 0.91 & 0.90 & 76.72\\
\hline
Author 4 (2019) & 0.91 & 0.90 & 76.72\\
\hline
Author 5 (2018) & 0.91 & 0.90 & 76.72\\
\hline
Author 6 & 0.91 & 0.90 & 76.72\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This is how it shows up. I tried using other browsers to view it, yet there are no horizontal lines. 
[image]

---

*Addendum*: Here's what is in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}} 
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png} 
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{mathabx} 
\usepackage{algorithmic} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{mdwmath} 
\usepackage{mdwtab} 
\usepackage{eqparbox} 
\usepackage{url}
```

Edit- [SOLVED] by removing the `mdwtab` package

Comment: Please make your code compilable. Which documentclass do you use? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Could it be possible that the arrayrulecolor was changed to white?

Comment: It can be certainly a rendering problem. Either zoom the table in your browser or print it to see if the lines are really printed.

Comment: document class is conference{IEEEtran},
I've used package tabularx
I tried changing browsers, with same results
arrayrulecolor wasn't defined by me, but I used a PDF reader with black backgroud but it still didn't show horizontal lines

Comment: The gaps in the vertical lines indicate the `\hline`s are present but white, but maybe something redefined `\hline`. The error is in the stuff left out of the question. Provide a short but complete sample document.

Comment: If the \hlines were present, they would have shown up when using a dark background, wouldn't they? They are n't showing up there either, but the vertical lines are.
Unfortunately, I wouldn't be able to share the whole document, I don't think I'm allowed to. But I could provide whatever I can. Do I need to share which packages I have used?
Also, \hline has worked for me previously.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I am also unable to replicate the issue you're experiencing, while using `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`. As others have already commented as well, the issue *must* be due to document setup aspects you haven't disclosed so far. Do tell us which packages are loaded in the preamble -- and in which order.

Comment: \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}  

\graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
  
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}  

\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}  

\usepackage{tabularx}  

\usepackage{colortbl}  

\usepackage{mathabx}  

\usepackage{algorithmic}  

\usepackage{array}  

\usepackage{mdwmath}  

\usepackage{mdwtab}  

\usepackage{eqparbox}  

\usepackage{url}  

Are used in the document, in the same order

Comment: @BOO1210 - I've taken the liberty of copying the code in your comment into the body of your query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You report that the preamble loads both the `mdwtab` package and the `colortbl` package. There appears to be an unfortunate [!] interaction between these packages that causes the lines drawn by `\hline` to be rendered in white and hence become invisible. As soon as you stop loading either the `mdwtab` package or the `colortbl` package, the horizontal lines reappear.

You need to decide if you can live without the `mdwtab` and/or `colortbl` packages (or both!). If you can, the problem will be solved.

In the following MWE (minimum working example), the problem is solved by not loading the `mdwtab` and `mdwmath` packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}} 
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png} 
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{mathabx} 
\usepackage{algorithmic} 
%\usepackage{array} % is loaded automatically by 'tabularx'
% The next two packages haven't been updated in decades
%%%\usepackage{mdwmath} 
%%%\usepackage{mdwtab} 
\usepackage{eqparbox} 
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
\caption{Comparison of Accuracy, Precision and Recall}
\label{table_example}
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Method & Accuracy & Precision & Recall \\
\hline
Author 1 (2019) & 97.93 & 76.72 & 76.72\\
\hline
Author 2 (2017) & 93.36 & 0.78 & 76.72\\
\hline
Author 3 (2019) & 0.91 & 0.90 & 76.72\\
\hline
Author 4 (2019) & 0.91 & 0.90 & 76.72\\
\hline
Author 5 (2018) & 0.91 & 0.90 & 76.72\\
\hline
Author 6 & 0.91 & 0.90 & 76.72\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had not orignially included the `colortbl` package, but did so when trying out the solution given by @loved.by.jesus. 
HOWEVER, removing `mdwtab` solved it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

In order to see, if is a **colour** or **thickness** problem (white lines or too thin to see) do following: (as described [in this line colour question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40666/how-to-change-line-color-in-tabular)) and [line thickness question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408868/how-to-change-hline-thickness-in-tabular)
Load the package `\usepackage{colortbl}` for colour
Load the package `\usepackage{makecell}` for thickness

And write `\arrayrulecolor{black}\hline` 
and/Or `\Xhline{5pt}` instead of `\hline`

For example:

```
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{makecell}

...

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Comparison of Accuracy, Precision and Recall}
\label{table_example}
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\arrayrulecolor{black}\hline %Forcing black colour in the \hline
Method & Accuracy & Precision & Recall \\
\arrayrulecolor{black}\Xhline{5pt} %Forcing black colour and 5pt thickness
Author 1 (2019) & 97.93 & 76.72 & 76.72\\
\arrayrulecolor{blue}\hline %Forcing blue colour in the \hline
Author 2 (2017) & 93.36 & 0.78 & 76.72\\
\hline
Author 3 (2019) & 0.91 & 0.90 & 76.72\\
\hline
Author 4 (2019) & 0.91 & 0.90 & 76.72\\
\hline
Author 5 (2018) & 0.91 & 0.90 & 76.72\\
\hline
Author 6 & 0.91 & 0.90 & 76.72\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

You will then now, if it is one of both problem

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tried using the package, but it didn't change anything. Still can't see the horizontal line on the Overleaf browser, Firefox and SumatraPDF

Comment: Well, my last guess, try to make the line thicker, if something happens. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the line size and using Xhline didn't change anything :/

Comment: Nothing? Not even the gap between the vertical lines of the table? That sounds really weird. Do not give up, solution will come. Please try to give a Minimal Example. A full sample of code where the error occurs that it is as short as possible, so that people my try a possible solution.

Comment: Nope. Just the vertical lines are showing up. Here https://imgur.com/K0lGc8i

Comment: The OP's issue was not caused by any of the possibilities you examine in this posting. Instead, it was caused by a rather unfortunate interaction between the `colortbl` and `mdwtab` packages.

Comment: @Mico, according to the comment of @BOO1210 above, it seems that it was `mdwtab` alone: unmaintained package. :\